# Select all rows which have other elements associated via join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of users and comments:

```
users(id, name)
comments(id, user_id, content)
```

I am looking for an (efficient) `SELECT` statement which will return only those `users`-rows which have at least one `comment` associated to them.

Usually I can do SQL easily but at the moment I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN comments c ON u.id = c.user_ID
```

`INNER JOIN` finds all the rows in users who whas linked data in `comments`

Comment: Isn't this just a normal join, also fetching users without any comments?

Comment: An `INNER JOIN` only returns rows where, in this case the user ID exists in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

`INNER JOIN` will do the the job. The reason why `DISTINCT` was added on the select statement is because it will only return unique user records and there maybe users have more than one record on the `comments` table.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN comments b
            ON a.id = b.user_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    users u
where u.id in (select id from comments where id=u.id)
```